# retrieving the maxspeed tag in openstreetmap

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I want to create an android application that warns me if I am to exceed the speed limit, and I thought of using the maxspeed tag in openstreetmaps , but when I got the data using the API I can't find the speedmax tag but it's there when I lookup the place in the site. is there any other way to retreive the max speed limit for each road to use it in my app ?

Comment: Could you post what you have tried already?

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for the maxspeed=* tag http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed (query taginfo on right sidebar)

Furhtermore there are different solutions for your task:

1. Ask existing map creators on help/data (lookup "Maps" in OSM Wiki)
2. Create a query for the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) maybe helpful is Overpass Turbo
3. Filter OSM Planet extracts on your own using osmosis and appropriate filter expressions

Please keep in mind, that dealing with OSM data can be difficult, as for example speed units depend on the country, same as defaults for untagged roads.

P.S. It's called OpenStreetMap (without -s) ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[maxspeed=*][bbox=31.454403,30.082119,31.454266,30.082093]

just use two points (LAN/LAT) on the same road to get the road details